# PostgreSQL & Heroku - cannot connect to the database

Tags: django, postgresql, django-south

I'm trying to add a column to a table via my Django app with South but keep getting the following error upon running the `python manage.py migrate <app name>` command:

```
conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not translate host name "ec2-107-21-99-105.comp
ute-1.amazonaws.com" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

Does anybody have an idea why this is happening? I'm a newbie to both South AND the PostgreSQL database management system (which Heroku uses), so I am more than a bit confused.

Comment: Seems like a DNS problem, cannot translate `ec2-107-21-99-105.compute-1.amazonaws.com` address.

Comment: What is that address? Where the database is located? Is this a problem on my end somewhere or with Heroku?

Comment: Do you have this address defined anywhere? `ec2-107-21-99-105.compute-1.amazonaws.com`, maybe in your settings.py?

Comment: This is what I have defined... `DATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.config(default='postgres://localhost')}`

Comment: Try this this line instead: `'default': dj_database_url.config(default=os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL'))`

Comment: Ok... but then do I need to define a `DATABASE_URL`?

Comment: No, that should be defined in your OS environment

Comment: I think it worked!!!! I still haven't figured out how to add the column... but happy there's no longer the error!!!!

Comment: Why it haven't add the column? Does it send another error?

Comment: I've added the answer, hope I can help with adding the column.

Comment: Thanks, would you mind helping me out in chat about the other issue if you have some time?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28919/discussion-between-paulo-bu-and-user1328021)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have defined your default database in `settings.py` like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': dj_database_url.config(default=os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL'))
}
```